# Multiple subscriptions without recalculate common part

Tags: ajax, angular, rxjs

```
const ex = ajax.getJSON('https://httpbin.org/get?a=24');
ex.pipe(pluck('args')).subscribe(x => console.log('Args: ', x));
ex.pipe(pluck('headers')).subscribe(x => console.log('Headers: ', x));
```

Code above([StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fgodr3)) initiates two ajax requests by one for each subscription.

What is correct way to initiate only one observable pipe/chain for all existing subscriptions?

I can achieve that with introduce a Promise for ajax([StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-prrqou)):

```
const p = new Promise(resolve => {
  ajax.getJSON('https://httpbin.org/get?a=24')
  .subscribe(res => resolve(res));
});

from(p).pipe(pluck('args')).subscribe(x => console.log('Args: ', x));
from(p).pipe(pluck('headers')).subscribe(x => console.log('Headers: ', x));
```

But I believe there must be some more convienient way.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-whats-changed-with-sharereplay-65c098843e95

Comment: @Vikas, thank you. Will learn about that now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) from comments solves my issue:

```
const src = tag => of(42)
  .pipe(tap(_ => console.info(tag, 'source called')));

const ex = src('shareReplay').pipe(
  shareReplay(1)
);

ex.subscribe(x => console.log('sa:', x));
ex.subscribe(x => console.log('sb:', x));
```

> ```
> shareReplay source called
> sa: 42
> sb: 42
> ```

[Full demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-prrqou)

Comment: That's also my goto operator for such cases :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [publish operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/publish.html) for that:

```
const ex = ajax.getJSON('https://httpbin.org/get?a=24').pipe(publish());
ex.pipe(pluck('args')).subscribe(x => console.log('Args: ', x));
ex.pipe(pluck('headers')).subscribe(x => console.log('Headers: ', x));
ex.connect();
```

The ajax request will take place just once, and only after the `connect()` method is called ([stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-stackoverflowcomposts56990383?file=index.ts)).

Comment: Can't result be received, when subscription was done after connect?

Comment: Oh, I think you're getting the two parts (args and headers) in different places of the code, uh? In that case, imo, maybe you should create an additional `ReplaySubject` just to reemit the last grabbed result from the backend. But I'll do a little research and come back if I have good news.

Comment: Significant part of my issue - I should be able to subscribe for it before and after actual data received. First subscribe should initiate data fetching, others waiting for it or receive it immediately, if already fetched. I add with Promise implementation to my question for clarity. May be `shareReplay` advice from comments will be useful, I read it now.